# Self-made linked list implementing List<E>

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list

I have to make a linked list as a quasi-homework task, about which I have already asked two questions about [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66685/self-made-linked-list) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66938/self-made-linked-list-iterator). Since the whole code is really big (400 lines approx.), I will include only the few functions I am asking you to review, although, if you need any more code, I will upload it.

Here is the `.add(int, T)` function:

```
public void add(int index, T data){
    if (getNode(index) == null){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else if (index<0 || index>=size){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    Node<T> crntNode;
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    crntNode = getNode(index);
    newNode.index = index;

    if (crntNode.previousNode != null) {
        crntNode.previousNode.nextNode = newNode;
    } else {
        firstNode = newNode;
    }
    crntNode.previousNode = newNode;
    newNode.nextNode = crntNode;
    crntNode = newNode;

    while (crntNode.nextNode != null){
        crntNode.index++;
        crntNode = crntNode.nextNode;
    }

    size++;
}
```

The `.get(int)` function:

```
public T get(int index){
    if(isEmpty() || index < 0 || index >= size){
        return null;
    }

    Node<T> crntNode;
    int count = size - index - 1;
    crntNode = lastNode;

    while (count > 0) {
        crntNode = crntNode.previousNode;
        count--;
    }

    return crntNode.data;
}
```

And the `.remove(int)` function:

```
public T remove(int index) {
    if (getNode(index) == null || isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else if (size == 1){
        size = 0;
        Node<T> crntNode = firstNode;
        firstNode = null;
        lastNode = null;
        return crntNode.data;
    }

    Node<T> crntNode = getNode(index);

    if (crntNode.nextNode != null){
        if (crntNode.previousNode != null){
            crntNode.previousNode.nextNode = crntNode.nextNode;
        } else {
            firstNode = crntNode.nextNode;
            firstNode.previousNode = null;
            size--;
            return crntNode.data;
        }
    }
    if (crntNode.previousNode != null){
        if (crntNode.nextNode != null) {
            crntNode.nextNode.previousNode = crntNode.previousNode;
        } else {
            lastNode = crntNode.previousNode;
            lastNode.nextNode = null;
            size--;
            return crntNode.data;
        }
    }
    crntNode = crntNode.nextNode;
    size--;

    for(int i = index; i < size-1; i++){
        crntNode = crntNode.nextNode;
        crntNode.index--;
    }

    return crntNode.data;
}
```

I thought a lot about improving these functions, but I can't seem to find a better concept. The reason might be my lack of knowledge, in which case, I hope you could help me.

Is this code efficient and error-safe enough to be used in real programming situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`add` paramater check**

> ```
> else if (index<0 || index>=size){
>     throw new NullPointerException();
> }
> ```

This isn't necessary, because `get` already catches these cases. You do the same in `remove`, where you check for `isEmpty`, which you already checked via the call to `get`.

You should also try to be consistent with your exceptions. `get` throws a `NoSuchElementException` in this case, while `add` throws  `NullPointerException`.

Oracles implementation throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which makes a lot of sense (and if you want to stay close to the List interface, you should use it as Tavian Barnes pointed out), but you could make a case for a `NullPointerException` or `IllegalArgumentException` if you wanted to. `NoSuchElementException` on the other hand would not match the description ([`Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)).

**Don't return null**

The only occasion you should return null is if the data inside the node is null. If a value is requested that doesn't exist, throw an exception. You violate this in `get` and `remove`, which will make it really difficult for a user in case they do store null in the list.

**Naming**

- `crntNode`: just add the extra characters, its not that much longer: `currentNode`.

**Assign value when declaring variables**

Instead of

> ```
> Node<T> crntNode;
> Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
> crntNode = getNode(index);
> ```

do this:

```
Node<T> crntNode = getNode(index);
Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
```

You do the same thing in `get`.

**Performance**

To increase performance, save the previous result of expensive method calls in local variables. For example, `getNode` is expensive, and you call it twice in `add` as well as `remove`.

**index**

You should get rid of `index` (not the parameter, but the node field).

In a linked list, nodes don't have an index, they only have a next node (and maybe previous if its doubly linked). Maintaining the index adds a lot of complexity and reduces performance, which can be avoided.

so just remove `index`, you are not using it anywhere anyways.

Comment: "there isn't a convention for the type of exception" ... Yes there is, [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

Comment: @TavianBarnes you are right, thanks. updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, valuable answer. My only concern is about dropping the `index` of nodes. How should I implement the indexOf method, if I don't have an index? I know it's doable, but seems a bit odd.

Comment: @AttilaHerbert just iterate over the list and check if the item is equal to the current item. keep a count, and then return that. even with an index you would still need to iterate, so it's not even worse for performance.

Comment: I need the `indexOf` method, because I am implementing the `java.util.List<E>` interface. I added the `index` only to be able to implement this method of the interface.

Comment: @AttilaHerbert yes, I didn't suggest to remove indexOf and perform the action i described outside of the list. iterate over the list, counting the elements until you found the correct one in indexOf.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I thought that would be considered "ugly", since it's pretty far away from OOP...

Comment: @AttilaHerbert Ugly or not, storing it is not an option. If you remove the first element, then you'd have to renumber the whole list. A linked list is damn slow even without doing such things, and by doing them, you're eliminating the only case when it's fast. +++ Storing it would be OK if it was a "stable" property of the node. But it's not as it can change without anything happening to the node or its neighbors.